# How do I set main URL a priority of 1.0 and subdirectory urls priority of 0.5 in sitemap.xml

Tags: php, xml, sitemap, sitemap.xml

How can I make the root index in the sitemap a priority of 1.0 and the rest of the sub directory files a priority of 0.5?

I'm using this php code to generate my sitemap on the fly when page is accessed.

As it is right now, it gives a priority of whatever the set value is

`$url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '0.5') );`

for every url in the sitemap like in this example:

[image: sitemap example]

PHP code that creates sitemap:

```
<?
$ignore = array( 'images', 'css', 'includes', 'cgi-bin', 'xml-sitemap.php' );

  function getFileList($dir, $recurse=false) {
  global $ignore;

    $retval = array();

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while ( false !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) ) {

        // Check if this dir needs to be ignored, if so, skip it.
        if ( in_array( utf8_encode( $entry ), $ignore ) )
            continue;

      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
        if($recurse && is_readable("$dir$entry/")) {
          $retval = array_merge($retval, getFileList("$dir$entry/", true));
        }
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => str_replace('./','/', $dir),
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }

  $dirlist = getFileList("./", true);  

    // sitemap creation
    $time  = time();
    $sitemap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitemap.xml';
    if ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1) { // 1 days

        $xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
        $xml->formatOutput = true; 

        // creating base node
        $urlset = $xml->createElement('urlset'); 
        $urlset -> appendChild(
            new DomAttr('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')
        );

            // appending it to document
        $xml -> appendChild($urlset);

        // building the xml document with your website content
        foreach($dirlist as $file)
        {
        if($file['type'] != 'text/x-php') continue;
            //Creating single url node
            $url = $xml->createElement('url'); 

            //Filling node with entry info
            $url -> appendChild( $xml->createElement('loc', 'http://www.airsahara.in'.$file['name']) ); 
            $url -> appendChild( $lastmod = $xml->createElement('lastmod', date('Y-m-d', $file['lastmod'])) ); 
            $url -> appendChild( $changefreq = $xml->createElement('changefreq', 'monthly') ); 
            $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '0.5') ); 

            // append url to urlset node
            $urlset -> appendChild($url);

        }
        $xml->save($sitemap);
    } // if time



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I figured it out.

I simply did this. I took this line of code and expanded it with an if and else statement.

went from this

```
$url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '0.5') );
```

to this

```
    if($file['name'] != '/') {
    $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '0.5') );
    } else {
        $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', '1.0') );
    }
```

**Update:** As per the comments of hakre

```
        if ($file['name'] != '/') {
            $p = '0.5';
            } else {
                $p = '1.0';
            }
        $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', $p) );
```

And this would be the shorthand of the if else statement

```
        $file['name'] != '/' ? $p = '0.5' : $p = '1.0';
        $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', $p) );
```

Comment: Tip: Do not branch for the statement(s), branch for the value only. In both cases you create the same element, it's just that the value differs. The code should express this intent.

Comment: You mean like this?

`if ($file['name'] != '/') { $p = "'priority', '0.5'"; } else { $p = "'priority', '1.0'"; }
   $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement($p) );`

Comment: more like this: `if ($file['name'] != '/') { $priorityValue= '0.5'; } else { $priorityValue = '1.0'; } $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', $priorityValue)`  - your variant would create a syntax error, as you can only assign one value to a variable and the comma in PHP doesn't work when you assing to a variable.

Comment: yep figured it out before you posted this last reply. I'm now going to update the answer with this and the shorthand of writing it.

Comment: @hakre would you please help me out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954994/proper-way-to-write-this-if-else-statement