# Proper way to write this if else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

How do I combine or write more efficiently this if else statement?

Is there a better way to write it without writing the entire thing twice?

The only difference is the two conditions placed on the first part to check if sitemap exists and then checks if the sitemap file modify time has changed in last 24 hours. If those two conditions are true then move forward, if those two conditions are false then move to the else part of the statement which simply creates the xml document without checking to see if the modified time has changed, since there was no file to check against.

```
$time  = time();
$sitemap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitemap.xml';
if (file_exists($sitemap)) { // if sitemap exists
    if ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1) { // 1 days

        $xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
        $xml->formatOutput = true; 

        // creating base node
        $urlset = $xml->createElement('urlset'); 
        $urlset -> appendChild(
            new DomAttr('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')
        );

            // appending it to document
        $xml -> appendChild($urlset);

        // building the xml document with your website content
        foreach($dirlist as $file) {
        if($file['type'] != 'text/x-php') continue;
            //Creating single url node
            $url = $xml->createElement('url'); 

            //Filling node with entry info
            $url -> appendChild( $xml->createElement('loc', 'http://www.'.$domain.$file['name']) );
            $url -> appendChild( $lastmod = $xml->createElement('lastmod', date('Y-m-d', $file['lastmod'])) );
            $url -> appendChild( $changefreq = $xml->createElement('changefreq', 'monthly') );
            $file['name'] != '/' ? $p = '0.5' : $p = '1.0';
            $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', $p) );

            // append url to urlset node
            $urlset -> appendChild($url);

        }
        $xml->save($sitemap);
    } // if time
} // if sitemap exists

else {

        $xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
        $xml->formatOutput = true; 

        // creating base node
        $urlset = $xml->createElement('urlset'); 
        $urlset -> appendChild(
            new DomAttr('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')
        );

            // appending it to document
        $xml -> appendChild($urlset);

        // building the xml document with your website content
        foreach($dirlist as $file) {
        if($file['type'] != 'text/x-php') continue;
            //Creating single url node
            $url = $xml->createElement('url'); 

            //Filling node with entry info
            $url -> appendChild( $xml->createElement('loc', 'http://www.'.$domain.$file['name']) );
            $url -> appendChild( $lastmod = $xml->createElement('lastmod', date('Y-m-d', $file['lastmod'])) );
            $url -> appendChild( $changefreq = $xml->createElement('changefreq', 'monthly') );
            $file['name'] != '/' ? $p = '0.5' : $p = '1.0';
            $url -> appendChild( $priority = $xml->createElement('priority', $p) );

            // append url to urlset node
            $urlset -> appendChild($url);

        }
        $xml->save($sitemap);
}
```

Comment: Put the creation in a function?

Comment: May be better on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hm, `if (file_exists($sitemap) && ($time - filemtime($sitemap)) >= 86400)`, or am I missing something? (Note the time difference would be in seconds, whether you want exactly those seconds, or the next day (think of daylight saving) or the exact same time on the next day (leap seconds) is up to you).

Comment: I was thinking of a function too. I was also thinking of the && or || to combine the two conditions. However, if I do that then if the file does not exist, it won't be created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be effectively the same check without duplicating the code:

```
if (!file_exists($sitemap) || ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1)) {
    // one copy of your routine
}
```

Here's the thought process in a truth table:

```
A = file_exists($sitemap)
B = ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1)

A | B | Outcome
--+---+--------
1 | 1 | 1
--+---+--------
1 | 0 | 0
--+---+--------   
0 | - | 1
```

Combining the positive outcomes gives us:

```
(A && B) || !A
```

Switching those two around allows us to short-circuit, making it unnecessary to check `A` again, so it simplifies to:

```
!A || B
```

Which, substituting back in the original expressions, gives:

```
!file_exists($sitemap) || ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1)
```

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `file_exists()` test. The second expression will only be tested if the first one failed.

Comment: I was already thinking of this solution, however if I do it this way, and if the file does not exist, then won't it give a php warning in stat for filemtime in the error log? That is what I'm trying to get away from is the error when the file isn't present on the server, yet this routine is trying to get the filemtime from the file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mike: What do you want to use in place of the file name and timestamp when it doesn't exist?

Comment: if the file doesn't exist, I want it to be created without getting the warning in the error log when checking the timestamp of a file that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? And what line causes it?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for /sitemap.xml in /includes/sitemap.php on line 65` and what causes it is if the sitemap.xml does not exist yet, the filemtime is trying to get the timestamp on the file that does not exist. so it causes the error. that is why I put the file_exists condition so I don't get that error now. But I just want to know how to make the code more efficient so as to not write it twice.

Comment: I have tested your answer and it is working fine. So by combining them like you did, it first checks if the file does not exist, and if it doesn't then it creates it. But if it does exist then it moves to the second part after the || and checks the timestamp?

Comment: so in essence, it won't check the timestamp unless the file exists?

Comment: @Mike: yes, exactly. It's called short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce everything to one function call to filemtime which returns false for unreadable/non existent files.

```
if(!($modified = filemtime($sitemap)) || $time-$modified>=1)){

}
```